# Error in start_col:end_col : argument of length 0 - UpSetR

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations, upsetr, upsetplot

I have a dataset like this:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40), a = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), b = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), c = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), d = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), e = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L))
```

I am using UpSetR to find all the possible combinations between a, b, c, d, and e and to get a nice graph.
This is my code:

```
library(UpSetR)
graph <- upset(df,
               sets = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
               order.by = "freq",
               empty.intersections = "on")
```

As you can see if you try using this code, there is an error message

```
Error in start_col:end_col : argument of length 0
In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Warning messages:
1: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
2: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
3: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
4: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
5: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
6: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
7: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
8: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
9: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
10: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
11: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
12: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
```

How do I solve the problem? I don't understand the problem as this dataset looks exactly as "mutations" dataset used as example here https://github.com/hms-dbmi/UpSetR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. It seems that when importing datasets it is important to convert them to dataframe before using UpsetR, thus `as.data.frame(df)` before using the code of UpsetR!
It works now.
This explains why in the dataset mutations the code was working correctly